# How to split table-row using display table-row?

Tags: css

Is there any way to split so that between the lists I could get the space?

```
li{
    display: table-row;
    background: red;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c62Jt/)

Here margin-bottom, padding-bottom not work. So how can I split the row?

question title is clearly describes that I need to split not just only the gap but should be separated.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `display: table-row;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ul {
    border-spacing:5px;
}

li{
    display: table-row;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: if you make the ul display:table, it should turn the gap white.  Only problem with this approach is it puts 5px all the way around not just the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Any way I have solved my problem by using the pseudo class like this:

```
li{
    display: table-row;
    background: red;
}
li:after{
    content: "";
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c62Jt/3/)

Comment: Have you tried my solution? I don't see how it doesn't do what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/c62Jt/4/

Comment: @ChrisLear I'll accept your answer, but I'll keep this answer as it would be more efficient for the margin around..